# karma + jasmine + angular + http GET's on every test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

As part of the apps bootstrap, it runs through a series of HTTP GET's to load assets.

My unit tests will throw "unexpected GET request" if i don't account for the fetch.  The issue is I have to include the GET on every test.  And there are about a dozen of the below.

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/action-icons.svg').respond('ok');
```

My question is; is there a better, global way, to account for the GET's in one place and include that call in all of my tests?

edit:

below is the entire block of assumptions that i have to include in every spec file. i would rather declare this block ONCE, somewhere, probably where global code can execute.

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/action-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/alert-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/av-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/communication-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/content-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/device-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/editor-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/file-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/hardware-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/image-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/maps-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/mdi-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/navigation-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/notification-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/social.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/social-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/toggle-icons.svg').respond('ok');
$httpBackend.when('GET', 'assets/iconsets/editor-icons.svg').respond('ok');
```

Comment: You can define the expectation for a set of tests using the [`beforeEach` method](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown). My question is: why are you bootstrapping the entire app to run unit tests?

Comment: you are right.  i am including the block of assumptions in the beforeEach... in every single spec file.  is there a way to reference one place where the assumptions can be executed and i can just include them in a spec file?

Comment: i dont think i can NOT go through angulars bootstrap because of `angular.mock.module('myHomeSearch');`.  once that runs, it will run angular's config block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$httpBackend.when` accepts a function as the url portion, as indicated in the api docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when), so you could do something like this if you didn't mind putting it at the top of each spec:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', function(url){
   //do your custom evaluations here (or just return true for everything...)
   if(url_is_like_any_of_yours){
     return true;
   }
}).respond('ok');
```

If you want to make it global, the other option is that you could use a decorator to intercept the $http calls directly. In my example, every $http.get call whose url was in the list would return the text 'ok'. You would include this file in your karma.conf like it was a spec, and it should run for every test.

```
angular.module('app').config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$http', function($delegate, $injector) {
        var originalGet = $delegate.get;
        //override the get function of $http and return a resolved promise
        $delegate.get = function(url, config) {
            var ignoreUrls = ['assets/iconsets/alert-icons.svg', 'assets/iconsets/av-icons.svg'];
            //if the url is not one that we are trying to ignore, let the request go through.
            if (ignoreUrls.indexOf(url) === -1) {
                return originalGet(url, config);
            }

            //the url is one we would like to ignore, so just return a promise with a fake http response 
            var fakeHttpResponse = {
                "data": "ok",
                "status": 200,
            };
            var $q = $injector.get('$q');
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(fakeHttpResponse);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Just make sure that you include this file after the angular.js file and also after your module declaration `angular.module('nameOfYourModule', [])`.

Here's a portion of the karma file I used to test this.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        //include angular and angular-mocks first
        'lib/angular/angular.js',
        'lib/angular/angular-mocks.js',
        //include your module declaration, the file with angular.module('app', []) in it
        'src/app.js',
        //include the http decorator file
        'specs/httpDecorator.js',
        //now include the rest of your source files and specs
        'src/**/*.js',
        'specs/**/*.js'
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: i think i worded my question wrong.  every spec file (that uses $timeout.flush()) has to have 14 $httpBackend.when() calls to account for assets that are fetched during bootstrap.  if i dont include them, the tests will fail.  i am wondering if there is a global area where i can include the when() calls once instead of declaring them in every spec file.  please see edited.

Comment: ive managed to include the spec in the conf but am receiving the error `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'set.querySelector')`.  any clue?

Comment: @0101adm,  I updated my answer again to better explain how to incorporate this into karma. In the karma config, in the files array, make sure that angular comes first, then the file that has your `angular.module('yourModuleName', [])` code, and then you can include this http interceptor file.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: ive included the file in the conf.  it does come after angular.  its now throwing `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'set.querySelector')`.  it must be something in the decorator because commenting it out removes the error.  im using angular 1.4.8.

Comment: Can you try debugging it in the karma debug tab and put some breakpoints on some of the lines to narrow down what exactly exactly is 'undefined'?

Comment: here are the last 4. `at extractFromSet (/Users/aaron/Documents/dev/mobilityre/apps/my-home-search/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js:21689)
     at processQueue (/Users/aaron/Documents/dev/mobilityre/apps/my-home-search/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14792)
     at /Users/aaron/Documents/dev/mobilityre/apps/my-home-search/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14808 at /Users/aaron/Documents/dev/mobilityre/apps/my-home-search/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16052`

Comment: My guess is that you are returning "ok" instead of the actual SVG data. I would suggest trying to run your app in the browser (not through karma), and see exactly what the result of the $http request for those svg files look like, and then change `fakeHttpResponse` in my example to return an exact copy of one of those responses.

Comment: in the spec, it errors at `$scope.$digest();` the following is the entire block ` beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, _$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$timeout_) {
         $timeout = _$timeout_;
         $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
         $scope = $rootScope.$new();
         $element = angular.element('<mre-about-agent></mre-about-agent>');
         _$compile_($element)($scope);
         directive = agent_directive_1.AboutAgent.factory()();
         $scope.$digest();
         controller = $element.scope()['agentCtrl'];
     }));`

Comment: will continue to chip away at this.  thanks for the start.

Comment: It would make sense that the `$scope.$digest` would fail, because when you run digest, the directive gets created and it immediately tries to fetch those svg images.

Comment: you were exactly right.  it was the content being returned.  replacing 'ok' with the actual data passed the tests.  what i'll do is if the url is found, i'll do the fetch there and include the data in the return 'data' member.  thanks again! superb.